# FaceBook Embedded Post Like Event callback

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have used an embedded facebook post on my page and i am trying to call an alert box when ever the like button gets clicked but the available solution is doing nothing.

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            alert("Hello");

        });
        // Code to detect clicking unlike
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (href) {
            alert('Unlike');
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Comment: I don’t think the fbAsyncInit event even fires when the SDK is embedded using parameters in the hash - that makes it initialize directly. Verify that via a debug output, and if it doesn’t fire, remove the hash from the SDK address, and then call FB.init in the fbAsyncInit handler function first.

Comment: It seems right But i couldn't figure it how to do...... @CBroe

Comment: Does it _seem_ right, or did you _verify_ that it executes the code inside the handler function?

Comment: I debug the whole code but it didn't execute.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: I have gone through the whole document but there no solution i could find for Embedded post Social plugin. All the Events for Likes are bounded to LIke Button.